# Offline cache of data in tablet for a asp.net MVC2 web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, caching

I need to give a survey(an asp.net MVC2 web app) to people on a tablet device. The survey runs on a browser which might suffer from internet outage, hence I need to have the device sync whenever its online. How can I cache data while the device is offline ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be with HTML 5 Local Storage.

http://www.kirupa.com/html5/html5_local_storage.htm